# problem with random scale of texture in object

Tags: node-editor, scale

I am having a problem with the texture scale.
I'm starting my studies with blender and I'm trying to create a brick texture. But I am unable to insert a standard scale for the entire object.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi there :) .Since u have plugged the UV co-ordinates to the mapping node can you attach an image of ur UV map

Comment: Hello :). To keep consistent texel density for all UVs, there's the [Texel Density Checker](https://gumroad.com/l/CEIOR) addon.

Comment: Thanks Jachym Michal!!
But is it work with only UV map or can i use it with shaders?

Comment: After researching a lot, I understood that the way you model the mesh can distort the scale of the material in some places of the object.
I wanted to understand how I can increase the size of an object or stretch it without this happening with the material / shader.